# Global function is not a function in latest browsers Microsoft Edge & Chrome

Tags: javascript

The following code works fine in my IE-10 but does not work in Chrome and Edge browsers. Any pointers will be appreciated.

form.jsp

```
 <div id="myDiv">
    <iframe id="iframeId" name="theIframe"  src="" frameborder="0" marginwidth="10" marginheight="20" scrolling="auto" width="100%" height="100%">
    </iframe>   
</div>
```

submit element in the form.JSP

```
<div id="submitButton">
    <input id="vButton" type="button" name="PullReport" value="Submit Me" onClick="document.theIframe.submitReport();"/>
</div>
```

myfunc.js

```
function submitReport () {
//this works
}
```

Error :
at this line `document.theIframe.submitReport()`

```
> Uncaught TypeError: document.theIframe.submitReport() is not a
> function
```

Comment: Why `document.theIframe.submitReport()`? Should be just `submitReport()`

Comment: I wonder why this works in IE11

Comment: Thanks, @ChayimFriedman, my bad, it is working in IE 10. I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Then I wonder why this works on IE10 :P

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Because global functions used to be attached to the named iframe property, rather than its `contentWindow` property.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know that

Comment: I changed the title because I was expecting something about the actual `submit()` function that exists on `form` elements, but this question is about a global function that happens to be partly named "submit".

Comment: If your iframe is in the same domain as your parent document, you could try `document.theIframe.contentWindow.submitReport()`...

Comment: @HereticMonkey, in my case, the iFrame and submit button elements are in the same file (.jsp) but the submitRreport() is in a different file(reqxx.js).  I got the following error when I tried your last suggestion Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submitReport' of undefined. please share if other ideas. thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it's more clear what functions are defined where, and what files are referenced on the host page and which are referenced in the iframe. Playing the guessing game is a waste of both our times.

Comment: updated the module names correctly